# Looping through the value in Textfield for Particular Text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, nspredicate

I have a TextField which has values as shown below.

```
@"Testing<Car>Testing<Car2>Working<Car3 /Car 4> on the code"
```

Here I have to loop through the text field and check for the text present within Angle brackets(< >).

There can be space or any special characters within the Angle Brackets.

I tried using NSPredicate and also componentsSeparatedByString, but I was not able to get the exact text within.

Is there any way to get the exact text along with Angle Brackets. Like in the above mentioned example want only

```
@"<Car>,<Car2> , <Car3 /Car 4>"
```

Thanks for the help in Advance.

Comment: Could you provide some kind of visual example of what you need to accomplish? What do you mean by "text present within < >"? What text?

Comment: Have modified the Question. Is it clear now ?

Comment: There are no angle brackets in your example. Please edit the question to add a meaningful example along with the expected result.

Comment: Have now posted the example with Angle brackets

Comment: And yet, "(Like , , )" isn't a clarification of your needs. Please double check your question, otherwise it's impossible for anyone to understand your needs. What do you mean by "check for the text"? Do you need to highlight the strings enclosed by angle brackets?

Comment: After looping the Text I want the final output to be only the Angle Bracket Text's. Like mentioned in the example only the final output needs to be <Car>, <Car2>,<Car3/ Car4>.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is Regular Expression. The pattern checks for `<` followed by one or more non-`>` characters and one `>`.

`enumerateMatchesInString` extracts the substrings and append them to an array. Finally the array is flattened to a single string.

```
NSString *string = @"Testing<Car>Testing<Car2>Working<Car3 /Car 4> on the code";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"<[^>]+>" options:0 error:nil];
__block NSMutableArray<NSString *> *matches = [NSMutableArray array];
[regex enumerateMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult * _Nullable result, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    if (result) [matches addObject:[string substringWithRange:result.range]];
}];

NSLog(@"%@", [matches componentsJoinedByString:@", "]);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve it in different ways. Now I am showing one of the way. You can place textFiled.text in place of str.

```
NSString *str =  @"This is just Added < For testing %@ ___ & >";
NSRange r1 = [str rangeOfString:@"<" options: NSBackwardsSearch];
NSRange r2 = [str rangeOfString:@">" options: NSBackwardsSearch];
NSRange rSub = NSMakeRange(r1.location + r1.length, r2.location - r1.location - r1.length);
NSString *sub = [str substringWithRange:rSub];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the textFiled.text can have multiple angle brackets along with regular text. Also, I need the final String along with Angle Brackets. Have updated my question with an example